# Using div id parameter as html tag

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm quite new in front-end development. It's Angular Material.
I'm trying to get access to my div element in other hmtl from parent.
What I'm trying to do.

**div.html**

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1>My work in progress</h1>
</div>
```

**main.html**

```html
<div layout="row" id="chart-section">
<div flex="20" >
  <myDiv />     
</div>
```

I'm using it in the same app.

**main_controller.js**

```js
(function ()
{
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.chart')
        .component('chartSection', chartSectionComponent());

    /** @ngInject */
    function chartSectionComponent() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/chart/components/chart-section/chart-section.html',
            controller: chartSectionController
        }
    }

    /** @ngInject */
    function chartSectionController() {         
    }       
})();
```

**myDivController.js**

```js
(function ()
{
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.chart')
    .component('in-progress', inProgressComponent());

  /** @ngInject */
  function inProgressComponent() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/chart/components/in-progress/in-progress.html',
      controller: inProgressController
    }
  }

  /** @ngInject */
  function inProgressController(chartService, $log) {

  }
})();
```

**main-module.js**

```js
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.chart', [])
        .config(config);

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
    {
        // State
        $stateProvider.state('app.restricted.chart', {
            url      : '/chart/:chartId',
            views    : {
                'content@app': {
                    template: '<chart />'
                }
            },
            params: {
                chart: null
            }
        });

        // Translation
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/main/apps/chart');
    }
})();
```

I'm using this theme http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/dashboard-project
How I can emplement it? Thank you.

Comment: trying how? post angular code; how you think that myDiv tag is linked to the div?

Comment: Can you specify which version of angularjs you are using?

Comment: if your using different controllers for views then use some data sharing methods like rooscope,broadcosting

Comment: Will you please elobarate your question?

Comment: I've added controller's codes, actually, it's angular material.

Comment: I'm working for customizing of this template http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/dashboard-project

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` to get an element by ID and then use `angular.element` to manipulate it, for example [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/akEGOq). You can use this technique within your main_controller.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div id="myDiv">
    <h1>My work in progress</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($element) {
  var myDiv = angular.element($element[0].querySelector("#myDiv"));
  myDiv.addClass("blah");
});
```

CSS

```
.blah {
  color: red;
}
```

[Element.querySelector() doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

[angular.element doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)